# Keep state of control after closing MDI child

Tags: c#, winforms, controls, mdichild

I need to keep all the points, series, etc of a chart inside a MDI child after closing the child and opening it again. Is this possible?

Comment: Serialize/deserialize its content. Or have it always available in model, so that new window takes it from there.

Comment: Hide control instead of closing and then show again?

Comment: Use serialization and take a look on Memento-Pattern.

Comment: How you are creating the chart and populating it? Put some code.